# Is their a posIndex in MS Access Queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to write a query like `SELECT substring(variable, startPosIndex, endPos) from Blah blah ;`

```
startPostIndex = indexPosition('#')
endPos = lenght(variable) - 1;
```

So basically my query to access will be

```
SELECT substring(variable, indexPosition('#'), lenght(variable) - 1) from Blah blah ;
```

The query that I have written to get if a field has anything after a "#" in a tuple is

```
SELECT DISTINCT Mid(geninq.entry,InStr(geninq.entry,"#"),Len(geninq.entry)) AS Expr1
FROM geninq
WHERE (((geninq.entry) Like "*[#]*"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is InStr: InStr(String, '#').